# How to configure my blog page

Tags: templates, blog

I've been learning WordPress for about 2 weeks now and I've got stuck in the "front-page.php", "index.php" and "front-page.php" controversy. Here's my question..

How can I make the /blog use the home.php template? At the moment, it is taken as a 404 page and triggers the 404.php template.

After a few looking up, I discovered I could manually create a blog page with just a title, but I don't know how feasible this is. Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

[Set front page as static page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307399/set-front-page-as-static-page/307410#307410)

The link above describes the other way around (static front page).
However, I hope it will help you to understand the mechanism, it's pretty easy.

In your case, you need to create a home.php file in your theme folder, and then go to settings >> read >> and instead of setting "start (front-page.php)" as your start page, set the reading option to "Show last blog posts".

WordPress will use that home.php file then and show your last posts as a front page.
I highly recommend installing "What the file" which will show which template you are using. (see the link I've posted)

So, front-page.php will be static front page (if set under settings > read).
The file home.php will show blogposts (if set under settings > read).

Clear? I hope that helps.

Please accept the answer as correct if I could help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very useful answer. I've done most of what you advise above, so here's where I am now...

I have the home.php file and have set the homepage displays to the latest post option. I expect everything to work, but when I go to /blog path of my site, it is handled by the 404.php template.

Comment: Hm, sounds like some sort of rewrite error of your .htaccess. Try flushing your rewrite rules by visiting setttings >> permalinks (triggers the flush). Backup your .htaccess and upload an original one from a fresh installtion. PM me with access so I can have a look and I'll see what I can do.